# Swift 4 - identifying only one text field as delegate for editingDidEnd etc

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I've kept this question free of specific context because I'm sure it will be helpful for others :

I have 2 IB outlet text fields :

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
```

I want to be able to disable buttons on my page until both have been filled out properly so I'm using the following delegates in ViewDidLoad() (I have added TextFieldDelegate to my VC.)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    textField1.delegate = self
    textField2.delegate = self
}
```

I then have some functions I will use to do the form validation and to take specific actions but to keep it simple let's say it simply prints to the console.

What I want to do is only check for validation in textField1 and not in textField2.  I.e. the desired output is that this prints for when user begins editing textField1 but if user edits textField2 nothing is printed.

I'm currently using :

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField1: UITextField) {
    print("TextField did begin editing method called")
}
```

But that is printing when either textField is edited.

I thought I've specified _ textField1 so not sure why both are triggering it?

There are some answers solving similar problems for Swift 3 and earlier.  In particular one answer referenced this link http://sourcefreeze.com/uitextfield-and-uitextfield-delegate-in-swift/ which i've found useful but am stuck on this error.

Comment: `if textField == self.textField1 {// Check Validation } else { }`

Comment: @Kuldeep Safer to use `===`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UITextField` delegate method allows you to identify that which `textField` is begin editing so you just need to check whether it's your 1st `textField` or not like this.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField === self.textField1 {
        print("TextField did begin editing method called")
        // Do your Validate for first text field
    } else {
        //Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's why the delegate function `textFieldDidBeginEditing` has a `textField` parameter. Renaming it does nothing.

If you want to discern your text fields, compare the `textField` parameter to your `IBOutlet`s, like so:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ text Field: UITextField) {
    if textField == textField1 {
        // Validate first text field
    } else if textField == textField2 {
        // Validate second text field
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have named the parameter that receives the `UITextField` reference that is *passed to the delegate method* `textField1`; the name of this parameter is nothing to do with the name of your property.  You could have called it `textField` and your code would still compile, despite not having a property called `textField`.

You need to compare the instance of `UITextField` that was passed to the delegate method:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField === self.textField1 {  
        print("TextField did begin editing method called for text field 1")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply set tag for both textFields as 0 and 1 then in your delegate method just check the tag of your textfield.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 0 {  
        print("TextField did begin editing method called for text field 1")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's first analyse your piece of code and see what is wrong:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField1: UITextField) {
    print("TextField did begin editing method called")
}
```

You renamed `textField` to `textField1`. However, that does *not* name the UI element that should be responsible for this action. Instead, that is a [function parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) which lets you access information  about the object that called the action from within your function, regardless of the outer scope. Instead, you should use the [`===` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538988), which checks whether two references point to the same object instance. So your code should become:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField === self.textField1 {
        print("TextField 1 did begin editing method called")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do both ways either you can put `if` condition on `textfield` like paul said or if you don't want textfield2 to work with any of the textfield delegate you can remove the line

```
  textField2.delegate = self
```